# Running function on grouped dataframe in pyspark using apply

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Python script that I am trying to translate into pyspark, I have a function `func` that in Python runs on a `pd.DataFrame` and returns a list of lists.

e.g.

```
[[14],[2,3]]
```

In python, I eventually run this on a grouped `pd.Dataframe` and is run as such:

```
data.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID').apply(func)
```

The output is a `pd.Series` with index as `CUSTOMER_ID` and each element is a list of lists relating to each `CUSTOMER_ID`

e.g.

```
CUSTOMER_ID
123                   [[14], [2, 3]]
124    [[1, 31, 5, 41, 12...
```

I am trying to use a `pandas_udf` to run this in pyspark as such:

```
schema = StructType([
  StructField("GROUP", ArrayType(IntegerType()))
])

@pandas_udf(returnType=schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def func_udf(data):
    return func(data=data)
```

and run the command:

```
data.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID').apply(func_udf)
```

However, I am receiving an error:

```
TypeError: Return type of the user-defined function should be pandas.DataFrame, but is <class 'list'
```

I am pretty sure this is to do with the way I am defining the output schema, however i'm not entirely sure how to handle this given the output is a list of lists of integers.

If it makes a difference, I have two versions of `func` available, the original python version that treats all operations as if running on DataFrames and a spark version that works on a spark DataFrame with one customer_id in it (i.e. not using group by) - I am calling the original python version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code produced the desired output.

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("CUSTOMER_ID", IntegerType()),
    StructField("GROUP", ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))
])

@pandas_udf(returnType=schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def func_udf(df):
    id = df.CUSTOMER_ID.iloc[0]
    gr = func(df)
    return pd.DataFrame({'CUSTOMER_ID':id,'GROUP':[gr]})

data.groupby("CUSTOMER_ID").apply(func_udf).show()
```